# Install GreenPAK Designer RPM

Tags: fedora, rpm

I am attempting to install closed source software from Silego, GreenPAK Designer, on a machine running Fedora 19. The supported installation packages on [Silego's Website](http://www.silego.com/s%20oftdoc/software.html) only target Ubuntu and Debian. I downloaded the .deb package and used Alien to convert to an RPM. So far so good, but a dry run of yum install showed dependency errors, which I solved by installing the necessary packages with yum:

- qt5-qbase
- qt5-qbase-gui
- qt5-qtdeclarative
- qt5-qtlocation
- qwt

Now, yum installed the above libraries in /usr/lib/ but the GreenPAK RPM defaults to /usr/local/bin as the output dir. I figured I could run

```
sudo yum localinstall --nodeps --noscripts greenpak-designer-x.x.x.rpm
```

and get a successful install but I received conflict errors relating to dirs such as '/', '/usr', '/usr/bin' etc. I worked around this issue with:

```
rpmrebuild -pe --notest-install --replacefiles --noscripts greenpak-designer.x.x.x.rpm
```

and removing the offending lines in the script. It allowed me to install rpm but the software is broken because of dependency issues (not surprisingly). From the system log:

> Jan  4 16:06:49 pelican gnome-session[1729]: /usr/local/greenpak-designer/bin/GP5: error while loading shared libraries: libicui18n.so.52: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

The machine has a /usr/lib/libicui18n.so.50

One thing I did not try is rebuilding my shared object cache with ldconfig, which sometimes solves problems with missing .so links when building from source but I don't see how that would apply in this instance (I'm not trying to link object files to libraries, rather simply trying to drop binaries in default install locations, no?)

Of course, I contacted the vendor and begged for an RPM. The contact was helpful but informed me the software folks are on a well deserved break. I thought I'd continue puttering with this in the meantime while I have time.

Any ideas? It seems the solution to this problem would be helpful when trying to install almost any closed source software targeting Debian on a Fedora box.